# django-axes failed login attempts are not consecutive

Tags: python, django, authentication, axes

django-axes **4.1.0**. I set the following configurations for django-axes which are working fine to soe limit:

```
AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = config('AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE', 
default=True, cast=bool)
AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT = config('AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT', default=5, cast=int)
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = config('AXES_COOLOFF_TIME', default=24, cast=int)
```

The user will be blocked after 5 failed login attempts as defined in the configs the problem is that they are not consecutive. If the user does 4 failed attempts followed by 1 successful login attempt and the a 1 failed login attempt, he will be blocked.

Is there a way to force the failed login attempts to be consecutive in order to block the user from logging in?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible via setting

```
AXES_RESET_ON_SUCCESS=True
```

however, it seems that you still have to wait for AXES_COOLOFF_TIME to pass.